# SWIPER.JS is not applying breakpoints on resizing screen

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I have added breakpoints on the Swiper and they work until you resize your screen.  The problem is when I'm on ex: 1200px and everything works as in the code. I start resizing to mobile(ex. 500px) and I can't swipe anymore. But when I refresh the page I'm able to swipe the carousel.
Example of code below.

```html
<Swiper
                            slidesPerView={5}
                            // spaceBetween={0}
                            breakpoints={{
                                1200: {
                                    width: 1200,
                                    slidesPerView: 5,
                                    spaceBetween: 5
                                },
                                992: {
                                    slidesPerView: 'auto',
                                    spaceBetween: 12
                                },
                                300: {
                                    slidesPerView: 'auto',
                                    spaceBetween: 30
                                }
                            }}
                            className={style['swiper-artists']}
                        >
```